# PHP - Filtering JSON array from multiple values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to filter out JSON response which I have decoded into an array. I can filter by a single objects value which in this case is the $lsr variable which is the commented out code below. What I am trying to do is now exclude all results which contain the value tx for the state. I am just getting null back or nothing at all. When I do a var_dump on $reportFeatures the array is empty and shouldn't be. What am I missing or over looking?

Here is a sample of a test JSON response I am working with. It should remove the first entry.

```
{"success":true,"error":null,"response":[{"id":"59c84e0bdb6be875458b45fd","loc":{"long":-100.73,"lat":38.47},"report":{"code":"G","type":"thunderstorm wind gust","name":"1 mi SSW Grigston","detail":{"text":60,"windSpeedKTS":52,"windSpeedKPH":97,"windSpeedMPH":60},"reporter":"public","comments":"Dime size hail also occurred at this location.","timestamp":1506296700,"cat":"wind","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-24T18:45:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-24T18:45:00-05:00","wfo":"ddc"},"place":{"name":"grigston","state":"tx","county":"scott","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c84703db6be8151f8b45fd","loc":{"long":-100.79,"lat":38.37},"report":{"code":"G","type":"thunderstorm wind gust","name":"7 mi E Shallow Water","detail":{"text":68,"windSpeedKTS":59,"windSpeedKPH":109,"windSpeedMPH":68},"reporter":"public","comments":"Measured 68 mph with a home anemometer.","timestamp":1506296640,"cat":"wind","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-24T18:44:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-24T18:44:00-05:00","wfo":"ddc"},"place":{"name":"shallow water","state":"ks","county":"scott","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c84703db6be8151f8b45fe","loc":{"long":-100.79,"lat":38.37},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"7 mi E Shallow Water","detail":{"text":1,"hailIN":1,"hailMM":25.4},"reporter":"public","comments":"Reported most marble with some quarter sized hail.","timestamp":1506296640,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-24T18:44:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-24T18:44:00-05:00","wfo":"ddc"},"place":{"name":"shallow water","state":"ks","county":"scott","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c848a8db6be82e288b4631","loc":{"long":-100.75,"lat":38.4},"report":{"code":"H","type":"hail","name":"6 mi SSW Grigston","detail":{"text":0.75,"hailIN":0.75,"hailMM":19.05},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"","timestamp":1506296400,"cat":"hail","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-24T18:40:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-24T18:40:00-05:00","wfo":"ddc"},"place":{"name":"grigston","state":"ks","county":"scott","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}},{"id":"59c83ffadb6be81b788b4602","loc":{"long":-94.13,"lat":46.33},"report":{"code":"D","type":"thunderstorm wind damage","name":"3 mi ESE Brainerd","detail":{"text":0},"reporter":"trained spotter","comments":"Numerous 6-8\" tree branches down along with a few stripped pine trees. time estimated from radar.","timestamp":1506288480,"cat":"wind","dateTimeISO":"2017-09-24T16:28:00-05:00","datetime":"2017-09-24T16:28:00-05:00","wfo":"dlh"},"place":{"name":"brainerd","state":"mn","county":"crow wing","country":"us"},"profile":{"tz":"America\/Chicago"}}]}
```

Here is the code I am working with and been trying. For brevity I didn't post it all the way through the loop at the end.

```
$json = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$result = json_decode($json, true);
$features=$result['response'];

// Lets filter the response to get only the values we want
$lsr = array(
    'hurricane',
    'tropical storm',
    'storm surge',
    'water spout',
    'tornado',
    'funnel cloud',
    'wall cloud',
    'thunderstorm wind damage',
    'thunderstorm wind gust',
    'hail',
    'lightning',
    'flash flood',
    'flood',
    'blizzard',
    'heavy snow',
    'snow',
    'sleet',
    'freezing rain',
);
/*
// filter features, remove those which are not of any of the desired event types
$reportFeatures = array_filter($features, function(array $feature) use ($lsr) {
    $reportType = $feature['report']['type'];

    return in_array($reportType, $lsr);
});
*/

// Lets filter the response to get the values we dont want
$ignoreState = 'tx';

// filter features, remove those which are not of any of the desired event types
// and also remove those from $ignoreState
$reportFeatures = array_filter($features, function (array $feature) use ($lsr, $ignoreState) {
    $reportType = $feature['report']['type'];
    $state = $feature['place']['state'];
    $isValidEvent = in_array($eventType, $lsr);

    return $ignoreState && $isValidEvent;
});

//var_dump($reportFeatures);

 foreach($reportFeatures as $report) {

    $reportID = $report['id'];
    $type = $report['report']['type'];
    $city = $report['report']['name'];
    $county = $report['place']['county'];
    $County = ucwords($county);
    $state = $report['place']['state'];
    $State = strtoupper($state);
    $mag = $report['report']['detail']['text'];
    $reporter = $report['report']['reporter'];
    $Reporter = ucwords($reporter);
    $comments = $report['report']['comments'];
```

Comment: You have `$reportType` but check `in_array` on `$eventType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose filter callback should be:

```
$reportFeatures = array_filter($features, function (array $feature) use ($lsr, $ignoreState) {
    // check if event is valid
    $isValidEvent = in_array($feature['report']['type'], $lsr);
    // check if state is not equal to `$ignoreState`
    $notIgnoredState = $feature['place']['state'] != $ignoreState;

    return $notIgnoredState && $isValidEvent;
});
```

Comment: Figured it had to be something with that `$notIgnoredState` line. Now what if I wanted to block everything but the state "tx"? Would I just change the ` $notIgnoredState` to ` $ignoredState`? Probably rename the variable to something like `$acceptedState`.

Comment: Yes, somehting like `$acceptedState = $feature['place']['state'] == $yourState;`